# Waking up web server using powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm building a script that perform http request in order to "wake up" some asp.net applications.

The following script is working, but is synchronous :

```
function WakeUp([string] $url)
{
    Write-Host "Waking up $url ..." -NoNewLine
    $client = new-object system.net.WebClient
    $client.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    $null = $client.OpenRead($url)
    $client.Dispose()
    Write-Host " Ok"

}
# Run your code that needs to be elevated here
@(
    "http://app1/",
    "http://app2/",
    "http://app3/"
 ) | % { WakeUp $_ }
```

I'd like to improve this script to avoid having the target site be awaken. In fact, the call to `OpenRead` waits for an answer before returning.

I've tried to use `OpenReadAsync`, but the call to `Dispose` occurs before the request is actually emitted and the target app is not waked up.

What are my options ?

**[Edit]** Applying Andy Arismendi's suggestions, my script is now :

```
$WakeUp = {
    Param ([string] $url)
    try 
    {
        Write-Output "Waking up $url ..."
        $client = new-object system.net.WebClient
        $client.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
        $null = $client.OpenRead($url)
        $client.Dispose()
        Write-Output "$url Ok"
    } catch {
        Write-Error $_
        throw $_
    }
}

$jobs = @()
# Run your code that needs to be elevated here
@(
    "http://app1/",
    "http://app2/",
    "http://app3/"
 ) | % { 
    $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $WakeUp -ArgumentList $_ 
    }

Receive-Job -Job $jobs -Keep
Wait-Job -Job $jobs
```

This seems to work as expected, but I loose the Write-Host. Any thought ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background jobs can make your workflow asynchronous.

- Convert the wake up function to a script block:

  ```
  $WakeUp = {
      ([string] $url)

      try {
          # Processing...
      } catch {
          throw $_
      }
  }
  ```
- For each URL spin up the script block as a background job.

  ```
  @(
      "http://app1"
      # More...
  ) | % {
      Start-Job -ScriptBlock $WakeUp -ArgumentList $_
  }
  ```

Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751187/how-to-capture-the-exception-raised-in-the-scriptblock-of-start-job/8751271#8751271) from another question to see how you can receive data from the background job and detect which failed.

**Update**

This addresses the issue in your version about not receiving output. You want to use `Wait-Job` before `Receive-Job` to allow them to finish because they are running asynchronously.

```
$WakeUp = {
    param ([string] $url)
    try {
        Write-Output "Waking up $url ..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        if ($url -eq "http://app2/") {
            throw ($url + " failed")
        }
        Write-Output "$url Ok"
    } catch {
        throw $_
    }
}

$jobs = @()
# Run your code that needs to be elevated here
@(
    "http://app1/",
    "http://app2/",
    "http://app3/"
 ) | % { 
    $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $WakeUp -ArgumentList $_ 
}

Wait-Job -Job $jobs | Out-Null
Receive-Job -Job $jobs -Keep
```

Comment: This seems to works, however I'm loosing my output. Is it possible to keep writing to the output ? I've tried with replacing `Write-Host` with `Write-Ouput`, creating a `$job = @()` array you did in the linked answer, and finally replacing Wait-Job by Receive-Job, but with no success

Comment: @SteveB See updated answer.

Comment: this allows me to get the output, but only at the end of all jobs. Isn't it possible to get an immediate output ? Without immediate output, I only see a black screen before everything is done.

Comment: @SteveB Yes you can use a `while` loop getting running events perhaps using `Get-Job -State Running` in combination with `Wait-Job -Any` or use `Register-ObjectEvent` (more advanced).

Comment: @AndyArismendi Your example above the update doesn't work. If I hardcode the url within the scriptblock it works fine so I'm assuming however the start-job is passing parameters is broken. Unfortunately I can't get the debugger to work in the script block to see what's going on.

Comment: @AndyArismendi Looks like the way you're consuming (or passing) arguments to the script block is wrong. I couldn't get it to work without using `$args` in the script block.